# Get title value from text link

Tags: javascript, html

I am not a Javascript expert at all but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have a link on a page that has a link structured similar to the code below. How can I extract the value of either the title reference or the Link? I figure that innerHTML would need to be used to get Link text but I can't get the element by ID or tag name.

```
<a href="#" title='titlevalue'>Link</a
```

Comment: If you can't target the element using id or tag name, what is it that identifies this link from other links on the page?

Comment: You cant get the element by ID o by tag name, can you add a class to it? something to be used as a wat to select it? or do you want to select it by title?

Comment: `document.links[2].title` will give you the title of the 3rd link on the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a specific ID to your link.
And then you can access it directly and get the valued you need.
Here is an example:
First, add an id to your link

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" title='titlevalue'>Link</a>
```

Then get it with javascript

```
var title = document.getElementById('myLink').title;
var html = document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML;
```

And altogether:

```js
var title = document.getElementById('myLink').title;
var html = document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML;
console.log("Title: " + title);
console.log("HTML: " + html);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myLink" title='titlevalue'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the elements with `tag name` using `getElementsByTagName` function. This will return array of elements with same `tag name`.
From that array, you can get the element you want and,

using `getAttribute` function, you can get the value of the specific `attribute`.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
const target = elements[0];

console.log('Href : ' + target.getAttribute('href'));
console.log('Title : ' + target.getAttribute('title'));
```

```html
<a href="#" title='titlevalue'>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data attributes like this:

```
<a href="#" data-title='titlevalue'>Link</a>
```

--> Instead of the `title` attribute you convert in into a data attribute like this: `data-title`

And in your javascript:

```
const link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
console.log(link.dataset.title);
```

And this should log: `titlevalue`

You can read more about data attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes